# Meteor add input attribute on click

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to add an attribute on click and cant figure it out how to do it. As seen below, I can update existing attributes but not add a complete new attribute to an existing input. Perhaps I am not using the correct terminology.
any help is appreciated.
Here is my helper.

```
"click input[name='spreads']:checked": function(event, template){
  template.find('input:radio[spreadsid=0]').setAttribute('data-schema-key', 'spreads');
}
```

HTML
 `<input type="radio" spreadsid="0" name="spreads" value="10">`

Comment: Add an empty attribute to the input then update it when you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant do that because if the input attribute is empty it throws an error in autoform. I am looking for add('data-schema-key', 'spreads') where 'data-schema-key' doesnt exist before in that input template load.

Comment: show your html, please

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a meteor application and it works just fine. Make sure that you set up the click event in the correct template. You could also test this out by using a jQuery selector. Instead of `template.find('input:radio[spreadsid=0]')`, try `$('input:radio[spreadsid=0]')`

Comment: It must of been late last night as the .setAttribute works for setting the property and the value.